# Jinja2 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, jinja2

```
{%for feed,tim in feeds,time %}
                        {% set nickname = feed.nick %}
                        {% set like = feed.like %}
                        {% set text = feed.text %}
                        {% set today = tim %}
                        {% set postid = feed.postid %}
                        {% set photo = feed.photo %}
                        {% set profile = feed.profile %}
                        
                        

                                {%for cmt in cmts %}
                                {% set nickname = cmt.nick %}
                                {% set cmt = cmt.cmt %}
                                {% set cmtid = cmt.cmtid %}
                                {% if cmtid == postid %}
                                <p class="description"><span>{{nickname}} </span> {{cmt}}</p>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}

                                <div class="comment-wrapper">
                                    <img src="../static/images/smile.PNG" class="icon" alt="">
                                    <input type="text" class="comment-box" id='cmt' placeholder="Add a comment">
                                    <button class="comment-btn" onclick=cmt_write()>post</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

succeeded in executing the for statement with one list in jinja2,
but we have to use two lists.

i try 2 list ( feeds, time ) use in jinja2

how to jinja2 for loop from jinja2

Is there a way to use two lists in jinja2?

Comment: Show us the definition of `feeds` and `time` in the view function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop over a combined list of two lists (of same length) you have to apply [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function on them. E.g.:

```
def view_function():
   feeds = [...]
   time = [...]
   
   feeds_and_time = zip(feeds, time)
   # Looks like this: [('feed_1', 'time_1'), ('feed_2', 'time_2')]
```

Then pass this new `feeds_and_time` variable to the render function. And in the template, modify the loop:

```
{% for feed,tim in feeds_and_time %}
```